# Updated Visual Studio, OpenCV Project No Longer Working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I had this working OpenCV project in visual studio 2017. I update Visual Studio to version 15.6.4 yesterday and the project no longer worked. The include files are still there, so are the dlls. The environment settings have not changed.

I tried opening other OpenCV projects that I know also worked for sure before the update and I'm getting the same error so I know my it's most likely not my code.

Here are the errors I'm getting:
[image]

I'd really appreciate any help if possible. It was a huge hassle for me getting the environment running the first time and now for this to happen is insanely frustrating, I just really want to start worrying about the actual code instead of all these inconvenient problems that are stopping me dead in my tracks.

Comment: Don't post images of errors, please. Post the errors as *text* in the question.

Comment: I assume you are not generating your Visual Studio project using CMake and using out of source building.

Comment: I downloaded the pre-built winpack for Opencv and it was working fine yesterday before the update

Comment: Does your compiler work if you just create a hello world console application.

Comment: Yes a hello world console app works

Comment: Fixed it, for some reason project was targeted to the wrong SDK version, I just needed to retarget it, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update, the project was targeted for Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 which was not found on my device.

I right clicked on the solution and clicked retarget solution and that fixed the problem.